# Console output is empty even though there is no error while compiling

Tags: c

When I build this code the following result appear:-

> 05:14:58 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.493ms)

But when i run the program the console output was empty.(nothing shown.white screen only).

Then i go to eclipse-workspace\sampleinput\Debug and run the .exe file.It worked on ms dos.

(The first program "Hello World" showed an output on console output screen.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    printf("enter number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("you enter %d",a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: no need to shout, wecan also read normal text

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking for *free help* to solve *your problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry there's nothing wrong with that code!

`scanf("%d",&a);` indicates to the program that it should *block* and wait for input, in particular a number (specified by `%d` for digit) and store that value at the memory address of the int variable `a`. For some more reading on [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

`printf("you enter %d",a);` will cause the program to print that number back to you through the console.

I hope that helps!